# get data in csv format in Asp.net mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, csv

trying to get data in csv format, having trouble to get this using jquery, but the same is working when i pass the parameter using hardcoded value, like

> its working..

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Export", new {SelectedAccountType = "1", FromDate = "2014-02-02", ToDate = "2014-02-02", SelectedAccount = "", SelectedUser = "", SelectedTeam = "" })" class="btn-primary" id="exportbutton2"> Export as CSV</i></a>
```

but when i try to pass the parameter value using jquery its not working,may be there is some problem in my jquery call can not able to figure it out. 
here is my

> jquery code that is not working

```
 @Html.TextBox("FromDate", null, new { @readonly = true, @class = "date-picker form-control" })
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.ToDate, new { @readonly = true, @class = "date-picker form-control" })
...
// other controls..
<a  class="btn-primary" id="exportbutton2"> Export as CSV</a>
$('#exportbutton2').click(function () {
            var accountType = $('#SelectedAccountType').val();
            var fromDate = $('#FromDate').val();
            var toDate = $('#ToDate').val();
            var accountId = $('#SelectedAccount').val();
            var userId = $('#SelectedUser').val();
            var teamId = $('#SelectedTeam').val();
            $.post(
            '@Url.Action("Export","Reports")',
            { "SelectedAccountType": accountType, FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate, SelectedAccount: accountId, SelectedUser: userId, SelectedTeam: teamId },
            function (data) {

            });
        });
```

method

```
public void Export(string SelectedAccountType, string FromDate, string ToDate, string SelectedAccount, string SelectedTeam, string SelectedUser)
        {
            var to_date = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);
            var from = Convert.ToDateTime(ToDate);
            var ac = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedAccount);
            var te = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedTeam);
            var us = Convert.ToInt32(SelectedUser);
            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            var list = reportService.GetReportsList(SelectedAccountType, from, to_date, ac, te, us);
            //First line for column names
            sw.WriteLine("\"Borrower First Name\",\"Borrower Last Name\",\"Requested URL\"");

            foreach (ReportList item in list)
            {
                sw.WriteLine(string.Format("\"{0}\",\"{1}\",\"{2}\"",
                                           item.BorrowerFirstName,
                                           item.BorrowerLastName,
                                           item.RequestedURL));
            }

            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=test.csv");
            Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
            Response.ContentEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
            Response.Write(sw);
            Response.End();
        }
```

whats wrong with my jquery , please help..

Comment: Why are you making all your parameters `string`? They should be `DateTime` and `int` (and remove all the `Convert.ToDateTime()` and `Convert.ToInt32()` methods). There is also no need to quote the names - just use `{ SelectedAccountType: accountType, FromDate: fromDate, etc. }`. And what is `var id = "PDF";`? - you don't appear to use the value of `id` anywhere. Also it should be `$.get(...)`. What is not working? Are the method parameters not populated in the controller method?

Comment: i have made all changes as your suggestion , method parameters are populated with the exact value, but still its not calling that method. and also there is no need of var id = "PDF";

Comment: The anchor is a `GET` request, but you're using jQuery as a `POST` request. Unless this action is decorated with `HttpPost`, you may want to change that to use `$.get`

Comment: @ Brad Christie i have changed it to  $.get(
           '@Url.Action("Export", "Reports")',
            { SelectedAccountType: accountType, FromDate: fromDate, ToDate: toDate, SelectedAccount: accountId, SelectedUser: userId, SelectedTeam: teamId },
             function (data) {
                 
             }); but still the same problem any idea ?

Comment: @StephenMuecke i have made all changes as your suggestion , method parameters are populated with the exact value, but still its not calling that method. and also there is no need of var id = "PDF";

Comment: Perhaps the [answers here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086162/handle-file-download-from-ajax-post) might help